# Appending data from one data frame onto another data frame in R (or stata)

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, append, stata

I am currently working in R, but I would also be able to tackle this problem in stata provided some help.

I have two very large datasets. One contains households and their locations, and the other contains weather data by date and location.  I ultimately need a dataset where each row is a household, and contains weather data matched to that household by location. In this dataset, each column would identify the date of that observation.

For the sake of simplicity, I created sample three data frames in R.

The first emulates my household data:

```
  house.id location.id
1    10001           a
2    10002           b
3    10003           c
4    10004           c
5    10005           a
```

The second emulates my weather data:

```
        date location.id temperature
1 2020-01-01           a          70
2 2020-01-01           b          71
3 2020-01-01           c          74
4 2020-01-02           a          61
5 2020-01-02           b          63
6 2020-01-02           c          61
7 2020-01-03           a          57
8 2020-01-03           b          50
9 2020-01-03           c          64
```

And the final one displays what my ultimate goal is:

```
  house.id location.id 2020-01-01 2020-01-02 2020-01-03
1    10001           a         70         62         57
2    10002           b         71         63         50
3    10003           c         74         61         64
4    10004           c         74         61         64
5    10005           a         70         62         57
```

As you can see, each household pulled weather data from its location id and appended it using additional columns which are named for their date (which was grabbed from the second dataset).

Obviously I created this third dataset manually, otherwise I wouldn't be asking for code here. I need to figure out how to automate the generation of the third dataset from the first two so that I can carry out the process on two much larger datasets.

Any help would be very much appreciated!!

Comment: In Stata this is fundamentally a `merge` on location identifier. From a Stata point of view, a wide layout is likely to be a poor choice for most purposes. Stay long.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to reshape wide.

Using data.table that would look like this

```
library(data.table)
dd <- setDT(dd)
dd <- dcast(dd, location.id ~ date, value.var="temperature")
```

Or, using base R:

```
dd <- reshape(dd, direction = "wide", idvar = "location.id", timevar = "date")
```

Then you can merge:

```
m <- merge(d, dd, by="location.id", all.x = T)
  location.id house.id 2020-01-01 2020-01-02 2020-01-03
1           a    10001         70         61         57
2           a    10005         70         61         57
3           b    10002         71         63         50
4           c    10003         74         61         64
5           c    10004         74         61         64
```

data:

```
d <- read.table(text = "  house.id location.id
1    10001           a
2    10002           b
3    10003           c
4    10004           c
5    10005           a
                ",header=T)

dd <- read.table(text = "          date location.id temperature
1 2020-01-01           a          70
2 2020-01-01           b          71
3 2020-01-01           c          74
4 2020-01-02           a          61
5 2020-01-02           b          63
6 2020-01-02           c          61
7 2020-01-03           a          57
8 2020-01-03           b          50
9 2020-01-03           c          64
                ",header=T )
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your weather data to the wide format and join to the household data. That should do it:

```
library(tidyverse)

#set up the household dataset
household_data <-  tribble(~"house.id",~"location.id",
                           10001,"a",
                           10002,"b",
                           10003,"c",
                           10004,"c",
                           10005,"a")
#set up the weather dataset
weather_data <-  tribble(~"date", ~"location.id", ~"temperature",
                         "2020-01-01","a",70,
                         "2020-01-01","b",71,
                         "2020-01-01","c",74,
                         "2020-01-02","a",61,
                         "2020-01-02","b",63,
                         "2020-01-02","c",61,
                         "2020-01-03","a",57,
                         "2020-01-03","b",50,
                         "2020-01-03","c",64)

household_data %>%
  full_join(weather_data %>%
              pivot_wider(names_from = "date",
                          values_from = "temperature"), # converts to wide format
            by = "location.id") # joins the two data frames
```

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  house.id location.id `2020-01-01` `2020-01-02` `2020-01-03`
     <dbl> <chr>              <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1    10001 a                     70           61           57
2    10002 b                     71           63           50
3    10003 c                     74           61           64
4    10004 c                     74           61           64
5    10005 a                     70           61           57
```

I don't know how to do it in Stata however!

Answer (score 0):

try to do it this way

```
hh <- structure(list(house.id = 10001:10005, location.id = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                       2L, 3L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                           -5L))
temperature <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
                                                 3L, 3L), .Label = c("01.01.2020", "02.01.2020", "03.01.2020"), class = "factor"), 
                              location.id = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                        3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), temperature = c(70L, 
                                                                                                                           71L, 74L, 61L, 63L, 61L, 57L, 50L, 64L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                         -9L))

library(tidyverse)
temperature %>% 
  left_join(hh) %>% 
  pivot_wider(c(house.id, location.id),
              names_from = date,
              values_from = temperature) %>% 
  arrange(house.id)
```